# Why Files misteriously disappear from xcode with this strange symptom?

Tags: xcode4.5

I use time machine and drop box to synchronize stuffs.

Recently I found that some files are gone.

However, the project compiles just fine as if the file is there. My friend cannot compile though.

This is very frustating. I got to find the missing files and then restore it from time machine and then readd that to xcode. I don't even know what files are missing.

I used dropbox and time machine. Looks like file disappear, the file names becomes "red" in xcode for a while and then poof it's gone. Xcode automatically remove the files from the project. The project still compiles fine which is frustating. If the project doesn't compile, I will know ah this file is missing.

Looks like somehow xcode still have the file but doesn't show it. Files is not on finder either.

What could possibly be the explanation and how to fix that.

I have clean projects to make sure that my computer do not use cached files.

1. It still compile fines in my computer
2. The file is still missing in project navigator
3. My friends' computer that uses the EXACT same files (connected to drop box) cannot compile

For example, xcdatamodeld files are crucial. In my computer it still run fine without that file even though that file is obviously needed. Xcode behaves as if the file is there all along.

My friends' try to compile the project and crash.

Also there is a PNG file. In my computer it runs fine with the icons showing up. In my friends computer the icons doesn't show up at all.

Comment: Did you have a question, or are you just venting?

Comment: Asking :). Change the question.

Answer (score 6):

For anyone who still have the problem, in my case Xcode6. It turns out somehow the "Show only files with source control status" and "Show recent file button" is enable. It located in the bottom of left sidebar.

[image: screen shot]

This somehow happen after I update os to Yosemite.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Go to the project navigator (top left folder symbol). Files that are not found by XCode are displayed in red. But since your project compiles fine, there should not be any that are required. Now click one of the "missing" files to activate it. Open the utility area on the right side, and show file inspector. Under "location" you find the full path of this file. Probably, your XCode project uses just references to these "missing" files that are stored somewhere else, and not in your project folder.

Comment: no missing red files. The file is simply not on object navigator anymore. Yet my project works fine but only on my comptuer

Comment: It's not red. It's just gone.

Comment: If these files are not at all in the project navigator, XCode does not use them, and thus they are not required for the project, if it can be built without them. But if you had other files in your project that were not required for building, this is not a XCode issue, and you had to restore them from backup in some way.

Comment: For example, I need a certain .PNG file. It works fine on my computer. The icon shows up. It doesn't work in my friends' computer. He doesn't have that .PNG file.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem ..then I added the files explicitly into our project…which resulted into Duplicate Symbols error …we solved that by following….
In Your Project go to targets-
At the bottom Bar of your Targets there are three options..
1.Add Target
2. Validate Settings
3. Build RUle..

Click on validate Settings….it will ask for you to remove the Duplicated files from the project do it…ur project would run fine